# Change TD font size based on screen resolution

Tags: css, fonts, screen, resolution

I'm looking for a very basic example that will change the TD font size if the screen resolution is 1024 * 768 or less.

The table and layout fit well at any resolution, but the standard font is slightly to large at this resolution. So I was hoping to find a way to just change that font..

Currently my css is in a separate file and contains this for the TD:

```
table.format td {
    padding: 3px 10px;  
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-size:10pt;
}
```

after the css is loaded could I determine the screen size and then overwrite this value ?

Any ideas or pointers ?

Comment: Use `em` or `%` insted of `pt` and `px`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css media queries like this:

```
table.format td {
    padding: 3px 10px;  
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-size:10pt;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
   table.format td {
     font-size:16pt; 
   }
}


@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
   table.format td {
     font-size:12pt; 
   }
}


@media screen and (max-width:1920px){
   table.format td {
     font-size:10pt; 
   }
}
```

you can change the max/min-width to suite your needs

Comment: Would be better to define font-size only in max-width:480px then max-width:1024px and finally min-width:1024

Answer (score 2):

Try this one for CSS3. It even reduces additional scripting in case browser window is resized.

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Link may be broken. Please add explanation here

Comment: Don't know what is problem with that server. You can have look at following article which explains same concept of using Viewport units. http://generatedcontent.org/post/21279324555/viewportunits